# Disabling dates based on first date picker

Tags: jquery

I have two date pickers. When I select certain date on 1st date picker then based on that selected date I need to disable 30 days for next DatePicker

Comment: Can you please provide Some more details about date Picker

Comment: Which _30 days_? Do you need something like http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/fmuerho1/1/?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question, this is your answer
I have edited Satpal sir's answer
    [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fmuerho1/8/)

```
startDate:
<input type="text" id="startDate" />
<br>targetDate:
<input type="text" id="targetDate" />


$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#startDate").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
        minDate: 0,
        showMonthAfterYear: true,
        onClose: function () {
            $(this).toggleClass('ui-state-focus');
        },
        onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
            var date = $(this).datepicker("getDate");
            date.setDate(date.getDate() + 30);
            $('#targetDate').datepicker('option', 'minDate', date);
        }
    });
    $("#targetDate").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
        showMonthAfterYear: true,
        onClose: function () {
            $(this).toggleClass('ui-state-focus');
        }
    });

});
```